# Which word is most correct in this case: re-settle or resettle?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, prefixes, compounds

In reference to the word *[settle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/settle)* as it pertains to the specific definition:

> Determine; decide on:

There is some debate internally on whether to use the word *[resettle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/resettle)* which only has one definition:

> Settle or cause to settle in a different place:

or to use a hyphenated word which seems most correct: *re-settle*

Since *resettle* doesn't seem to pertain to *opposite* meaning of my specific definition, I think the hyphenated form is correct.  Can anyone shed some light on this situation?

Comment: Could you provide a sentence as an example of what you mean? I don't understand why resettle wouldn't work, as it literally means "to settle again."

Comment: Looking at Sven Yargs' answer, there is only one word here, with two alternative spellings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that Oxford Dictionaries Online provides a single definition of *resettle* is quite misleading, since the word can actually be used in a number of senses. A better treatment of the word appears in the full *Compact Edition of the Oxford English Dictionary* (1985), which begins with this:

> **Resettle,** *v.* Also **re-settle**. To settle again, in various senses.

In other words, any form of the word that conveys some sense of the idea "to settle again" can be rendered as *resettle* or as *re-settle*. The decision of whether to hyphenate or to close up the word is thus a matter of style preference—your own or your publisher's—and not connected to a generally understood difference in meaning (as might be the case with, say, *recreation* and *re-creation*).

In general, the tendency in U.S. English (and perhaps in British English, too) is to dispense with hyphens after prefixes like *re-* except in instances where a clear split in the meanings of hyphenated and unhyphenated forms exists. No such split exists here, notwithstanding the contrary inference you drew from Oxford Dictionaries Online.